# The group member's supported protocols are incompatible with those of existing members

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm facing an issue related to Kafka.

I'm having my current service (`Producer`) that sends the message to a Kafka topic (`events`). The service is using `kafka_2.12 v1.0.0`, written in Java.

I'm trying to integrate it with the sample project of `spark-streaming` as a `Consumer` service ([here](https://github.com/jjmeyer0/spark-streaming-example) using kafka_2.11 v0.10.0, written in Scala)

The message is sent successfully from `Producer` to the Kafka topic. However, I always receive the error stack below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InconsistentGroupProtocolException: The group member's supported protocols are incompatible with those of existing members.
    at ... run in separate thread using org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils ... ()
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:577)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:571)    at com.jj.streaming.ItemApp$.delayedEndpoint$com$jj$streaming$ItemApp$1(ItemApp.scala:72)
    at com.jj.streaming.ItemApp$delayedInit$body.apply(ItemApp.scala:12)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)     at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)   at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at com.jj.streaming.ItemApp$.main(ItemApp.scala:12)
    at com.jj.streaming.ItemApp.main(ItemApp.scala)
```

I don't know the root cause. How can I fix this?

Comment: Tin Nguyen, did you find the solution for this? i'm also facing the same issue

Comment: hi @Satish, no I didn't.

Answer (score 6):

This happens in my configuration when I attempt to add a consumer to the cluster that is using a different partition assignment strategy from the previous ones.

For example:

```
partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RandomAccessAssignor
```

mixed with or defaulted to:

```
partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor
```

Comment: In order to find out if this is your issue as well, use `kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server SERVER:9092 --describe --group GROUP --state`
In the result, look for ASSIGNMENT-STRATEGY.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @john Cairns and @Iraj Hedyati, check assignment strategy assigned to the consumer group. Different clients create consumer groups with different default strategies. for example

when I used kafka command-line client ( java ), it has created a consumer group using the 'range' strategy.

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group aeprocessor5 --state

GROUP                     COORDINATOR (ID)          ASSIGNMENT-STRATEGY  STATE           #MEMBERS
aeprocessor5              172.16.1.11:9092 (1003)   range                Stable          1
```

whereas when I created consumer group using go client using `sarama` library, it's using 'round-robin strategy.

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group aeprocessor5 --state

GROUP                     COORDINATOR (ID)          ASSIGNMENT-STRATEGY  STATE           #MEMBERS
aeprocessor5              172.16.1.11:9092 (1003)   roundrobin           Stable          1
```

so, if the group already exists and has a different strategy then `InconsistentGroupProtocolException` is reported.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the issue with exception `InconsistentGroupProtocolException` is already described in another answer here (that we have different partition assignment strategies inside the same consumer group simultaneously), but I would like to add how to resolve the issue without any downtime, either if we need intentionally to change assignment strategy (e.g. in order to decrease Kafka rebalance latency with newly eligible strategy) or due to switching to another Kafka consumer library.

Initially, we need to figure out what is the previous and new desired partition assignment strategy (also mentioned in another answer how to define the previous one), and after that, we should explicitly specify both these strategies for a consumer group in the new release.
For that, need to specify property `partition.assignment.strategy` or something similar based on Kafka consumer library (e.g. `partitionAssignor` for Camel Kafka)

```
partition.assignment.strategy=strategy1,strategy2
```

If you specify multiple partition assignment strategies for a consumer group, the priority of the strategies is determined by the order in which they are listed. The first strategy listed will have the highest priority, followed by the second strategy, and so on. During rebalancing, the consumer group coordinator attempts to use the partition assignment strategy with the highest priority. If that strategy fails or encounters any issues, the coordinator falls back to the next strategy in the list.

In my case, I was required to switch from `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor` into `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor`, so I specified the following

```
partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor,org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor
```

with that, we have smooze deployment without any downtime, and in further releases we could leave only a single strategy.

Answer (score -1):

For me, it is because I am using same consumer group to subscribe 2 different topics accidentally.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31378439)

Comment: What is the issue with single consumer group sub to multiple topics?