# Kafka Consumer RegExp: stale consumers

Tags: java, performance, apache-kafka, architecture, kafka-consumer-api

I subscribe to [Kafka Topics by RegExp](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html). There are 5 topics matching the given pattern. Four of them has 10 partitions. And the last topic has 12 partitions. So, there are 52 partitions at all.

I have 5 running instances and each of them starts 10 consumers. So, there are 50 consumers at all. I expect that the load is spread horizontally across all the consumers. So, each consumer reads 1 partition except two of them because total number of consumers is less than the whole partitions count.

Though the reality is a bit different.

[image: A single consumer reads multiple partitions]

[image: Most consumers remains stale]

In short, here is what happens

1. There are 50 consumers subscribing to multiple topics by RegExp. All found topics has 52 partitions totally.
2. Each consumer tries to subscribe to 1 partition from each found topic. There are also two consumer subscribed to 1 partition from the single topic because the latter has 12 but not 10 partitions.
3. 12 consumers are working whilst 38 remains stale due to unavailable partitions to read.

Is there any way to force Kafka consumer to read 1 partition maximum with RegExp subscription? In this case, I can make all consumers start work. Or maybe there is a different approach that allows to read multiple topics respecting the number of partitions and running consumers?

Comment: Please share your existing consumer code. How exactly are you starting 10 per instance? And no, you cannot set the number of partitions per consumer using subscribe method; you can only do this with manual assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's about [partition.assignment.strategy](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#consumerconfigs_partition.assignment.strategy) Kafka property. The default value is `RangeAssignor` which leads to assigning partitions on topic basis. That leads to spreading load between consumers unfairly.

We set the property to `RoundRobinAssignor` and it helped.

[image]

Though you should be careful when you deploy new version with different `partition.assignment.strategy`. Suppose you have 5 running consumers with `RangeAssignor` strategy. Then you redeploy one with `RoundRobinAssignor` strategy. In this case, you get an exception on consumer replacement. Because all consumers in one consumer group should provide the same `partition.assignment.strategy`. The problem is described [in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486969/the-group-members-supported-protocols-are-incompatible-with-those-of-existing-m)

So, if you want to change the `partition.assignment.strategy`, you have several options:

1. Redeploy all consumers and then deploy new ones.
2. Specify new `group.id` for the new consumers.

Both of these ways have pros and cons.