# InconsistentGroupProtocolException while bringing a Kafka consumer up

Tags: apache-kafka

We have 2 spring Kafka applications, recently we started observing `InconsistentGroupProtocolException` in one of our application logs file.
It turned out we have two consumers in each applications with same group.Id ‘consumer-common-grp’ but different topics i.e topic A in application 1 and topic B in application 2.

As a fix we changed the name of the consumer group in application 1 and it fixed our issue. But my question is how this was working before? As we didn’t face this issue before, and as per my understanding Kafka considers group name + topic for uniqueness not just group name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka doesn't "fence" consumer groups... More than one app is more than welcome to share the string. When one (re)starts, it'll cause all in the group to rebalance, as well as full consumer stops. Yes, the fix to this is to ensure there is no overlap (can be accomplished by better certicate policies and ACLs to access any topic).

As far as "inconsistent protocol", you may ensure your apps are using the same `kafka-clients` dependency version and [assignment strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486969/the-group-members-supported-protocols-are-incompatible-with-those-of-existing-m)

Comment: Hi @OneCicketeer, We had 2 different topics T1 (2 partitions) and T2 (3 partitions)
We had 2 consumers with the same group Id ABC
Assigned consumer C1 (from application 1) to T1, consumer C2 (from application 2) to T2
@KafkaListener(topics = "T1", groupId = "ABC", concurrency = "10") --> application 1
@KafkaListener(topics = "T2", groupId = "ABC", concurrency = "10") --> application 2

Comment: concurrency is 10 because most of the topics have 10 partitions on prod environment.
I checked both application is using same version of spring-kafka API. 
I fixed the issue by changing the group id in application 1 such as @KafkaListener(topics = "T1", groupId = "XYZ", concurrency = "10") my question is what is wrong in the above topology and how it is linked to InconsistentGroupProtocolException

Comment: The posts here seem to give an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486969/the-group-members-supported-protocols-are-incompatible-with-those-of-existing-m

Comment: yes thanks a lot @OneCricketeer, I just found out both applications were using different assignment strategy. One was with default witch is RangeAssignor and the other one was with RoundRobinAssignor